# Custom one-to-many relationship in EF 6.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to write custom logic for a one-to-many relationship? Suppose I have the following classes:

```
public class ProductIncompatibility
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductIncompatibilityId { get; set; }
    public int ProductIdA { get; set; }
    public int ProductIdB { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductIdA")]
    public virtual Product ProductA { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductIdB")]
    public virtual Product ProductB { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductIncompatibility> IncompatibleProducts { get; set; }
}
```

When I execute the following Linq-query:

```
Products.Select(it => new { it.ProductId, it.IncompatibleProducts })
```

or

```
Products.Include("IncompatibleProducts")
```

I would expect all ProductIncompatibility-records where ProductIdA = ProductId || ProductIdB = ProductId.

Is it possible to specify this logic, for example using the modelBuilder?

Comment: Have you tried this and it didn't work? `Product` already returns the properties you want so `Select` isn't needed. A simple `Products.Include("IncompatibleProducts").ToArray()` would return all underlying records.

Comment: I think this is not a valid EF model configuration. It's not quite clear how EF will map `Product.IncompatibleProducts` property. You really need 2 collection properties - one for each `ProductIncompatibility` FK.

Comment: I know the default way is to use 2 collection properties. Unfortunately we are using WCF Data Services, so the client that uses the server would see these 2 collection properties as well. It is possible for the client to combine these collections to find out the incompatible products, but it's not such a neat solution...